# Laravel Cashier issue when using reportUsageFor()

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

When trying to add usage to an existing subscription, an error is thrown

```
  at vendor/laravel/cashier/src/SubscriptionItem.php:203
    199▕     public function reportUsage($quantity = 1, $timestamp = null)
    200▕     {
    201▕         $timestamp = $timestamp instanceof DateTimeInterface ? $timestamp->getTimestamp() : $timestamp;
    202▕
  ➜ 203▕         return $this->subscription->owner->stripe()->subscriptionItems->createUsageRecord($this->stripe_id, [
    204▕             'quantity' => $quantity,
    205▕             'action' => $timestamp ? 'set' : 'increment',
    206▕             'timestamp' => $timestamp ?? time(),
    207▕         ]);

      +3 vendor frames
  4   app/Console/Commands/CustomerInvoicing.php:120
      Laravel\Cashier\Subscription::reportUsageFor("price_1Je5SrK0R6HrlyvmOo5qPZOy")

      +13 vendor frames
  18  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

The user has a valid subscription on their account, as shown in this test snippet

```
$user = User::find(7);
        if ($user->subscribed('default')) {
            $this->info('This user is subscribed');
        }
        $user->subscription('default')->reportUsageFor('price_1Je5SrK0R6HrlyvmOo5qPZOy', 12);
```

**Output**

```
root@a17cce8ef092:/srv/app# php artisan invoicing:customer
This user is subscribed

   ErrorException

  Trying to get property 'owner' of non-object

  at vendor/laravel/cashier/src/SubscriptionItem.php:203
    199▕     public function reportUsage($quantity = 1, $timestamp = null)
    200▕     {
    201▕         $timestamp = $timestamp instanceof DateTimeInterface ? $timestamp->getTimestamp() : $timestamp;
    202▕
  ➜ 203▕         return $this->subscription->owner->stripe()->subscriptionItems->createUsageRecord($this->stripe_id, [
    204▕             'quantity' => $quantity,
    205▕             'action' => $timestamp ? 'set' : 'increment',
    206▕             'timestamp' => $timestamp ?? time(),
    207▕         ]);

      +3 vendor frames
  4   app/Console/Commands/CustomerInvoicing.php:120
      Laravel\Cashier\Subscription::reportUsageFor("price_1Je5SrK0R6HrlyvmOo5qPZOy")

      +13 vendor frames
  18  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Comment: What other debugging have you done? Have you tried printing the output of `$user->subscription('default')` and verifying that everything looks right on the subscription? Have you printed `$user->subscription('default')->hasPrice("price_1Je5SrK0R6HrlyvmOo5qPZOy")`?